# button background colouring in android

Tags: android, background-color

i've created an android application which creates 50 button dynamically,which works perfectly, but the problem is that i can't put some background color for these buttons dynamically  using code like

```
buttons[i][j].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor));
buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor));
```

my code is as given below, can anyone please tell me some solution for giving background color for button

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyMain extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mymain);
        createCalender();
    }
    public void createCalender()
    {  
        LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
        LinearLayout rowLayout=null;
        Button[][] buttons = new Button[10][5]; 
        int count=51;
        int tab=1;
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) 
        {
            if(count%5==1)
            {
                rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                rowLayout.setWeightSum(5);
                layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout,param);
                count=count-5;
            }
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                buttons[i][j]=new Button(this);
                buttons[i][j].setText(""+tab);
                buttons[i][j].setHeight(35);
                buttons[i[j].setWidth(75);                                            
                buttons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.color.mycolor);
                buttons[i][j].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
                tab++;

                rowLayout.addView(buttons[i][j],param);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you are not calling the setBackgroundColor before tab++ ?

Comment: i've even done that ..........see my updation.........but still its not working

Comment: copied and pasted your code, it works. Make sure your color is not fully transparent. Can you post your color's "value" from the xml? Also which api level you are using?

Comment: <color name="mycolor">#857500</color>

Comment: try Neil's answer then. On android 4.0+ your code works tried both on device and emulator. 
Also make sure you are not changing drawable/color of buttons in another place

Comment: buttons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.color.mycolor); works but now the button text disappears

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33831/discussion-between-user2018186-and-desu)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to use:

```
buttons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.color.mycolor);
```

That way you overwrite the existing background image (which is a `Drawable`) with the colour you want.

Comment: now when i put that code instead I'm getting...........java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kotouch/com.kotouch.MyMain}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070000

Comment: because what you get from getColor() is a color not a resource therefore cannot be used as one.

Comment: hey buttons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.color.mycolor); works but now the button text disappears

Comment: that's because you are setting text and button to same color?

Comment: then how do we set the button text color

Comment: Create another colour in your resources and use that one!

Comment: i tried buttons[i][j].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); but still not working..........even i tried exactly what u said like buttons[i][j].setTextColor(R.color.black);....still not working...........see my updation

Comment: try buttons[i][j].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);? Just making sure that the color isn't blending into the background.